# disable scrollbar and mousewheel but not scrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how can i hide scrollbars in a website, disabling scroll by mouse but being able to reach hidden areas of the page with the jquery scrollTo plugin function? (click on a button and page scroll to the target element)?

thanks!

Comment: try looking at this stack overflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378946/1524085

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable scroll bars a simple css:

```
html, body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

To scrollTo please look at this example:

http://www.adriantomic.se/development/scroll-to-the-top-with-jquery/

Comment: @DavideGadaldi you don't need to use the `scrollTo` plugin for something like this. See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/ALryC/)