# on scroll, trigger event at the same time while hiding scroll bar and hiding overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a website similar to this http://www.grannyssecret.com (just the landing page).

if you go there and scroll up, hidden footer appears smoothly, then if you scroll down again the footer goes down.

my HTML file can imitate the same thing when I click the button, but it doesn't work when I try to animate footer by scrolling a mouse wheel.

the problem is that scrolling event is firing multiple times.
also, when overflow is set to hidden scrolling event doesn't fire.

Any idea to work my way around this problem?

I can't seem to use jquery on `jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vd6qgLL2/3/`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: If you look at the site it uses jQuery to add a class on scroll. Then it uses CSS animation to slide the footer block into view. using     `transform: translate(0,100%);` to `transform: translate(0,0);` Its a nice way of doing it without parallax

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ["wheel"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event instead of "scroll".

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("wheel",  function () {
//your code here
});
```

Please find your refactored fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mp0a6Ln6/