# jQuery scroll listener for user input (even if page isnt scrollable)

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have a jQuery or javascript listener for when a user tries to scroll, even if the web page is not scrollable? I need to execute some code when the user tries to scroll down, even if the web page is short enough that there is no scrolling.

Note this solution doenst need to work for touch-screens.

UPDATE I need different code to execute when the user tries to scroll up as opposed to down.

Comment: for which events do you listen (or do you expect) when the content is to short to scroll and no scrollbar is visible?

Comment: Could you check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378243/catch-scrolling-event-on-overflowhidden-element) ?

Comment: @silverfighter I want to listen for either.

Comment: @Thanassis_K That solution doesn't work in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: used `on` instead of `bind` and inserted the direction of scrolling.
Also added `DOMMouseScroll` in order for this to work in Firefox.

Just use:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e){
    // To catch up or down scroll:
    e = e.originalEvent;
    // delta == 1 = down, delta == -1 = up;
    var delta = e.wheelDelta > 0 || e.detail < 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Or bind it to something else if you prefer.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt detailed enough with my question, ive updated it now. I need to execute different code when a user tries to scroll up as opposed to down.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: You can put that code anywhere you want. As long as it is withing `<script>` blocks or within a JavaScript file that is include with those script blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY < 0) {
        alert("Scrolled down");
    } else if (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY > 0) {
        alert("Scrolled up");
    }
});
```

It seems like different browsers give you different deltas.
**This solution doesn't work in all browsers like IE!**

---

I really suggest you to have a look at Brandon Aaron's Mousewheel-Plugin for jQuery, which works on IE, too: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

With that plugin you should be able to get a better solution:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if (deltaY < 0) {
        alert("Scrolled down");
    } else if (deltaY > 0) {
        alert("Scrolled up");
    }
});
```

Comment: Im getting this error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Objects #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use? Do you use the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers and advice but ive found a version that works for me:
[Get mouse wheel events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            console.log('scrolling up !');
        }
        else{
            console.log('scrolling down !');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't that just the same answer as we gave?

Comment: For some reason it worked when yours didnt for me. Im doing this through a CMS so there may be some platform qwerks that I dont know about.