# Catch 'mousewheel' event on a body with hidden overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

how is it possible catch the "mousewheel" event on a **body** with an **hidden overflow**?

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378243/catch-scrolling-event-on-overflowhidden-element) but it doesn't work on my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery mousewheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel).

**EDIT**: Here is the code from my plugin:

```
var self = this;
var scroll_object;

if (!navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/) &&
    self[0].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'body') {
    scroll_object = $('html');
} else {
    scroll_object = self;
}
...
self = $.extend(self, {
    scroll: function(amount) {
        var pos;
        amount = Math.round(amount);
        if (scroll_object.prop) {
            if (amount > scroll_object.prop('scrollTop') && amount > 0) {
                scroll_object.prop('scrollTop', 0);
            }
            pos = scroll_object.prop('scrollTop');
            scroll_object.scrollTop(pos + amount);
            return self;
        } else {
            if (amount > scroll_object.attr('scrollTop') && amount > 0) {
                scroll_object.attr('scrollTop', 0);
            }
            pos = scroll_object.attr('scrollTop');
            scroll_object.scrollTop(pos + amount);
            return self;
        }
    },
...
self.mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    if (delta > 0) {
        self.scroll(-40);
    } else {
        self.scroll(40);
    }
    return false;
}, true);
```

Comment: I am already using it. But it doesn't fire on a body with hidden overflow (no scrollbar)

Comment: @MarcoCalì I'm using it here http://terminal.jcubic.pl/multiply-interpreters-demo.html (jquery terminal) and it work. But in Webkit browsers I scroll html element instead of body, but the event is attached to body.

Comment: The code I post is a plugin attached to `$('body').plugin` so `this` becomde `$('body')` in my code. In firefox `scroll_object` need to be a body.