# Catch mousewheel up or down with jQuery/JS, without actually scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to catch whether the mousewheel is triggered and whether it's scrolled up or down without actually scrolling the page (body has an overflow: hidden).

Any idea's how I can achieve this using jQuery or pure javascript?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( /* scroll up */){ }
    else { /* scroll down */ }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378946/3509874

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch scrolling event on overflow:hidden element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378243/catch-scrolling-event-on-overflowhidden-element)

Comment: That possible "duplicate" question doesn't address how to prevent scrolling.

Comment: And it's a bit outdated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I rarely promote plugins but this one is just excellent (and relatively small in size) :

https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/

It'll allow to do something like this :

```
$(window).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

  if (delta == 1) // going up
  else // going down

  // all kinds of code

  return false;
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPmjym?editors=001

---

Update - at this point the mousewheel plugin could be replaced with the `wheel` event if legacy browsers need not be supported:

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {

  var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;

  if (delta > 0) // going down
  else // going up

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This disables the scrolling.

**NOTE**: Notice it only stops scrolling if you hover over the element.

> ```
> $('#container').hover(function() {
>     $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(){ 
>        console.log('Scroll!'); 
>        stopWheel(); 
>     });
> }, function() {
>     $(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
> });
>
>
> function stopWheel(e){
>     if(!e){ /* IE7, IE8, Chrome, Safari */ 
>         e = window.event; 
>     }
>     if(e.preventDefault) { /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */ 
>         e.preventDefault(); 
>     } 
>     e.returnValue = false; /* IE7, IE8 */
> }
> ```

Quoted from [amosrivera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571370/jquery-disable-scroll-when-mouse-over-an-absolute-div)

**EDIT**: To check which way it is scrolling.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
   } else {
      // upscroll code
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: I have to add - if the page isn't actually going to be scrolled, the second script will not work.

Comment: You are right. But since there is still no feedback from OP, I can't guess why such functions are needed.